# Crystal Report display collapse when one field allow can grow

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

My crystal report display not in correct format when I allow one field of it to "Can Grow".

Before allow "Can Grow" :

[image]

After Allow :

[image]

So how to solve the problem?

Here is what I have set :

[image]

Last edit:

[image]

Comment: set it to 100% maybe it will be fixed. try it

Comment: Can you make it clear? I don't which property that we need to set 100%?

Comment: haha. now i know why its not working. insert all the fields in the text object. not the {?DearMr} only.. All fields like mine. I inserted The Company Name, The Address, and the Conctact and if there's more. So that if the 1 field will grow the other one can adjust its location

Comment: if its not yet working just inform me so that i can give you more details on how to do it.

Comment: can you give me a big screen shot of what have you done. link will be fine. And Check my post at the bottom part. read it again

Comment: did you see it? I added already

Comment: how many text object did you use? i think in every obeject they have their own text object. Inside The text object insert your field without text object then just arrange them inside the big text object

Comment: you can follow furito answer... it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Or try this.

- Create a text Object.
- Insert all your fields in that text Object base in your order.
  How to insert? Cut the field then edit text object then paste.
- Then in the properties of text object check the Suppress Embedded
  Field Blank Line.
- Then You can check also if you want the Can grow of text object

This is the Sample Output inside the Textobject

[image]

And the output is this

[image]

Cotabato to House is the Company name.
Sinsuat to Philippines is the Address.
Then Numbers is the contact.

They compres because i shorten the size of textobject so that they will execute the funtion of can grow

Your Output must be like this. hmmm
[image]

Your Final Output must be like this. No more '[' or ']' that can be seen inside the textobject.

Data was just Sample

[image]

Comment: did you do like that?

Comment: Please insert many words as much as possible for {Company Address} you will see the result

Comment: maybe your not following the steps that i provide

Comment: review this maybe you will get it now perfectly

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible for you, you can create a section just for this field.

If you put your field which can grows and take 2, 3 or more lines in it's own section it will display all the lines but keep it separate from the other fields.

And in the case that it has one line the display will be like you want as well.

- Edit : Advantage of this method : you can create a formula in the suppress formula of this new section, like if your text is null or empty, just suppress the section. Like that you can win some space in your report

Regards,